# Multisite 'Welcome User Email' SITE_NAME returns 'network' name, not the name of the blog

Tags: multisite, user-registration

I've set the 'Welcome User Email' under 'New Site Settings' to the following:

> Dear USERNAME:
> Welcome to the SITE_NAME portal which provides information on our policies, processes, >procedures, templates and forms.  You can also view the SITE_NAME news, calendar and >contacts.
>
> Here is your login information:
> Username:USERNAME
> Password: PASSWORD
>
> Click here to log in - LOGINLINK

The problem is that when the user receives the email, the "SITE_NAME" parameter is the 'network name' for the wordpress install, not the name of the actual blog they have just registered to.

This code https://gist.github.com/1331582 overcomes the issue for the user confirmation email that initially gets sent out when a user is added, but I need it to apply to the 'Welcome User Email'.

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is basically the same as in the case of `wpmu_signup_user_notification()`.

```
function wpmu_welcome_user_notification($user_id, $password, $meta = '') {
    global $current_site;

    $welcome_email = get_site_option( 'welcome_user_email' );

    $user = new WP_User($user_id);

    $welcome_email = apply_filters( 'update_welcome_user_email', $welcome_email, $user_id, $password, $meta);

    // Get the current blog name
    $blogname = get_option( 'blogname' );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'SITE_NAME', $blogname, $welcome_email );

    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'USERNAME', $user->user_login, $welcome_email );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'PASSWORD', $password, $welcome_email );
    $welcome_email = str_replace( 'LOGINLINK', wp_login_url(), $welcome_email );

    $admin_email = get_site_option( 'admin_email' );

    if ( $admin_email == '' )
         $admin_email = 'support@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

    $from_name = get_site_option( 'site_name' ) == '' ? 'WordPress' : esc_html( get_site_option( 'site_name' ) );
    $message_headers = "From: \"{$from_name}\" <{$admin_email}>\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"" . get_option('blog_charset') . "\"\n";
    $message = $welcome_email;

    $subject = apply_filters( 'update_welcome_user_subject', sprintf(__('New %1$s User: %2$s'), $blogname, $user->user_login) );
    wp_mail($user->user_email, $subject, $message, $message_headers);

    return false; // make sure wpmu_welcome_user_notification() doesn't keep running
}
add_filter( 'wpmu_welcome_user_notification', 'bbg_wpmu_welcome_user_notification', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Legend! I just needed to tweak the function to _bbg_wpmu_welcome_user_notification_ so it was the same as being called in the add_filter. Thanks!